# Need explanation pcnt_fork()

Tags: php, pcntl

I am new to pcnt_fork,

```
<?php
  $pid = pcntl_fork();
  echo $pid;
  if($pid) {
  // parent process runs what is here
  echo "-parent\n";
   }
  else {
  // child process runs what is here
  echo "-child\n";
  } ?>
```

ouptut :
25347-parent
0-child

my question is , here $pid will be the process id of the child process i.e 25347 right?
then it should echo only parent then why its also giving 0-child as a output...can anyone explain

Comment: are these the only 3 echo statements you are using?

Comment: yes, these are only three statements

Comment: Anything coming after `pcntl_fork()` will be the output of *both* processes.

Comment: You mean to say , after fork we will have 2 process one is child and other is parent.Does it mean the if-else statement will be executed two times once for child and then for parent.And i have one more doubt after fork which process will be exceuted first child or parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the state looks like after a fork operation:

```
           fork()
      +------+-----+
    child    |   parent
-------------+------------
> echo $pid  | > echo $pid
0            | 4650
```

Comment: ok, this processes will be exceuted asynchronously ,means parent process will be complete its execution first then child process will start its execution am i right ?

Comment: @SupriyaPansare No, it happens at the same time (which is why I "drew" them next to each other); which output comes first is not strictly defined, but it seems that the parent output comes first.

Answer (score 0):

[pcntl-fork](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.pcntl-fork.php) (just like fork) forks a child but it doesn't closes the parent.

In the end you have 2 running processes, the parent and the child.

The 2 lines of print that you are receiving come from 2 different processes: the parent that has received the pid of the child and the child itself.

Answer (score 0):

On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent's thread of execution, and a 0 is returned in the child's thread of execution. On failure, a -1 will be returned in the parent's context, no child process will be created, and a PHP error is raised.